# Remove rows if a specific columns contains anything other than numbers?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df:

col1    col2
 1        4
 4       ab1
 5       1s,2
 6        5
 3        24
 5        xy
```

If col2 contains any character other than numbers drop those rows from the data frame.

The final dataframe will look like:

```
col1    col2
 1        4
 6        5
 3        24
```

How to do it using pandas in effictive way ?

Comment: `df = df[df.id2.str.contains(r'^[0-9]$')]`

Comment: `df = df[df.col2.str.encode('utf-8').isna()]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df=df[df.col2.apply(lambda x: x.isnumeric())]
```